# Raising a bounty on someone else's question / raise attention for an unanswered question which is not my own

Tags: support, feature-request, bounty

I've recently come across a few "really good" unanswered questions, tagged within [pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pydantic) (Python). I want to raise attention for these questions, even raise a bounty perhaps on behalf of the OP. I understand that this isn't currently a feature, but I figured this would be a good place to start.

How can I raise attention for someone else's questions? Also, I'm pretty active in the topic/tag [pydantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pydantic). Are there any tools for me as a community person who's highly active? Is there a roadmap for such curation or other similar functionality?

Comment: You can raise a bounty on someone else question. I did it myself. You even get badges for.

Comment: AH! Thanks for pointing that out! I just raised a bounty. Perfect.

Comment: you are welcome, but be aware it is the same game as it would be your own question. Means, even if you won't get an answer that you expect or even not an answer at all, the points are gone.

Comment: Is there a doc with more information on how bounties work *for q's which aren't your own*?

Comment: There's a complete FAQ on MSE: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/1099857) and in the help center [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](/help/bounty)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) describes, you can [set a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to any question you want draw attention to:

> If you see a question that has not gotten a satisfactory answer, a
> bounty may help attract more attention and more answers. Slice off
> anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation, and
> attach it to any question as a bounty. You do not need to be the asker
> of the question to offer a bounty on it.

The [bounty-system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) works the same as you would ask for yourself.